# Issue while using small screen qualifier in Android

Tags: android

I am still working on my android application and I am facing once again an issue. 
I have defined a small screen ressource and I noticed that the ADT automatically resize the Layout to support the small screen resolution, but while I am doing a test in the emulator, I don't have the result I expected, as shown in the following screen shot:

[image: Small screen test]

You can notice that the text displayed under some bouton are not totaly visible.
Here is the result when I test the application in the emulator whith a normal screen size :

[image]

I really need your advise to resolve this issue. Thank you !

Regards.